# Extract Contacts data in WP 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, phone-number

I am not a complete noob but I need to extract phone numbers from the contact list on Windows Phone 7. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an article on MSDN, titled [**How to: Access Contact Data for Windows Phone**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286416%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). In this article is explained how to access the contactlist and extract information from it. Also [**this**](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/How-to-choose-a-Contact-and-get-Contact-details-in-a-WP7-app) article from *windowsphonegeek.com* explains on how to access the contact and get details from a contact, such as the phonenumber(s).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You should use [PhoneNumberChooserTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.phonenumberchoosertask%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) to let user select a contact from his contact list.

A sample: [Click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394021%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use microsoft Contacts class in Microsoft.phone.userdata namespace .

You can use search function and event handler after completion of search to be get notified.
[refer the documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.userdata.contacts%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)